# how can i create a Alert Dialog in init method in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

i want to run this code in init method but it throws an exception
how can create an alert in javafx in this method without any problem ?

```
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
    alert.setTitle("Error Dialog");
    alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Error Dialog");
    alert.setContentText("Ooops, there was an error!");
    alert.showAndWait();
```

i need to show a message before app start and i dont want to use JoptionPane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way of doing this in the `init` method.

[From the JavaDoc of `Application.init`:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html#init--)

> NOTE: This method is not called on the JavaFX Application Thread. An application must not construct a Scene or a Stage in this method.

If you need to display some exception in the `init` method to the user via JavaFX GUI, save enough info to create & display the message in a field, display the message in the `start` method and simply shut down the application via `Platform.exit` after the `Alert` is closed:

```
private boolean exceptionInInit = false;

@Override
public void init() {
    try {
        // do something
    } catch (Exception e) {
        exceptionInInit = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    if (exceptionInInit) {
         Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
         alert.setTitle("Error Dialog");
         alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Error Dialog");
         alert.setContentText("Ooops, there was an error!");
         alert.showAndWait();

         // make sure platform shuts down even though primary stage was never shown
         Platform.exit();
    } else {
        // normal startup
    }
}
```